# Regex replace for preceding zero twice in string with different condition

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, regex, reactjs

I have string XY4PQ43 and I want regex replace should output XY04PQ0043 in JavaScript. For **first number** in a string I want zero prefix if its single digit to make it **2 digits** and for **second number** in string I want prefix zeros if its less than **4 digit number**. Below output expected for regex.

- AB**1**CD**123** => AB**01**CD**0123**
- MN**12**XYZ**1** =>   MN**12**XY**0001**
- LJ99P1234 => IJ**99**P**1234**

Any jsfiddle or codepen example preferred

Comment: Your examples differ in more than just some zeroes...

Answer (score 1):

For that given string, you can apply the following regex:

```
var _str = 'AB1CD123';
_str.match(new RegExp(/([A-Z]{2})([0-9]{1,2})([A-Z]{2})([0-9]{1,4})/))
```

It outputs an array with values matched starting from 1 to 4, where 2 and 4 are the ones you need to manage. For those values you can apply logic - add leading zeros - by checking their length and merge them afterwards. Try it in browser console.

*Note: it works for this specific example. For other examples you need to adjust the length matched.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
function format(text) {
  let match = /^(.*?)(\d+)(.*?)(\d+)$/.exec(text);
  return [
    match[1],
    match[2].padStart(2, '0'),
    match[3],
    match[4].padStart(4, '0'),
  ].join('');
}

console.log(format('AB1CD123'));
console.log(format('MN12XYZ1'));
console.log(format('LJ99P1234'));
```

Comment: Thanks! I have created small modified demo here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/t4kows1s/)

Comment: Warning, you code won't work for 'LJ99P1234'. You should use the answer I provided because the other answer given doesn't take into account the flexibility of your format. The previous answer didn't account for the single letter between the number, it only assumes that there will be two letters. Thus the solution is incorrect. The regex I used is very general and catered towards your question instead of your examples.

Comment: Please never post code-only answers on Stack Overflow.